# Run an Php Function inside a Js Function called by an OnClick

Tags: javascript, php

thanks for reading and take your time to asssist me, i apologize for the grammar, im not native english speaker, thank you for your understand =)

First, i have a Menu non static that grows by adding new threads... the id for each thread is +1 per thread, thats why i send 1, 2, 3, 4... as parameter on the function, because thats the ID on the DataBase.

```
            <a onClick="LoadThread(1)">How to make a Pizza</a>
            <a onClick="LoadThread(2)">The true Colors</a>
            <a onClick="LoadThread(3)">Name for a Thread</a>
            <a onClick="LoadThread(4)">Fix your computer</a>
```

Then i have my JavaScript Function. Inside it, i would like to take the id from the parameter and use it in a Php function SendQuery to select the ID and then load the threads with the function LoadThread(). And this will update a DIV in the webpage.

```
            function LoadThread(id){

            var jsID = id;

            <?php 

                require_once ("select_on_click.php");
                $varMakeQuerys3 = new Make_Querys; 
                $varMakeQuerys3->SendQuery("SELECT * FROM Threads WHERE idThread=\""."".jsID.""."\"");
            ?>


            document.getElementById('textContent').innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($varMakeQuerys3->LoadThread()); ?>;
        }
```

This is the webpage im working on: www.josecaballero.tk/Vlog
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Useing jQuery:**
Put your php script into a separate file. I'll call it `script.php`
Here is what your LoadThread function should look like.

```
LoadThread(id)
{
    var jsID = id;
    $().ajax({
        url: "www.josecaballero.tk/location/of/script.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data:{ID: jsID },
        success: function(result){
            document.getElementById('textContent').innerHTML = result;
        }
    });
};
```

Your PHP should look like this:

```
 require_once ("select_on_click.php");
 $ID = $_POST["ID"]
                $varMakeQuerys3 = new Make_Querys; 
                $varMakeQuerys3->SendQuery("SELECT * FROM Threads WHERE idThread=\""."".$ID.""."\"");
echo json_encode($varMakeQuerys3->LoadThread());
```

Comment: Thank you for take you time to help me, web development is new for me, im giving my best

So, i did exactly what you said, but nothing is happening. The LoadThread() function returns this string: 

        return "<h3>".$row["Title"]."</h3>"."<p>".$row["Content"]."</p>";

im not sure what "sucess" does and what catchs this result from the php function, could you give me a little explain please =)

Comment: What every your php is echo is what is contained in the result variable. success runs when the ajax was successful.

Comment: I put an alert after the Sucess to check if it was working... but it doesnt, is not execution the alert, so whats the problem here?

the only thing i think i can change is this part:
url: "load_thread.php",

already try with the full url
url: "www.josecaballero.tk/Vlog/load_thread.php", but it didnt work =/

Comment: error: function (a,b,c) {alert([a." ".b." ".c." "])}, - Add this code. after data:{ID: jsID },

Comment: @Kaba you also need to have jQuery on your page, this won't work if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run PHP inside Javascript since PHP runs on the server-side and JS the client.

The only way to "call" PHP from your JavaScript is to use techniques like AJAX.